# flexbox and wrap property

Tags: css, flexbox

I am developing and app with phonegap. I wanted to use the flexbox to layout some buttons in my main application area.

Can somebody explain why this http://jsfiddle.net/apYLB/ doesn't wrap elements in latest chrome?

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -moz-box-align: end;
    box-align: end;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    justify-content:space-around;
    height:100%;
}
.flex-item {
    margin:0 10px 25px 0;
    width:86px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.flex-item img {
    max-height:80px;
}
```

They are laid horizzontally and only 3 and a half boxes appear.

Comment: Here's a handy chart for matching up properties/values from the different drafts:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have quite a few things not quite right here.  First, you're mixing old properties with new properties (`display: -webkit-box` is from the 2009 draft, but `-webkit-flex-flow` is from the standard draft).

Second, none of the 2009 Flexbox implementations support `box-lines: multiple`, which is required for enabling wrapping.  Sadly, nearly all mobile devices support only the 2009 draft.  Firefox versions that support the modern specification currently do not support wrapping either (flex-flow and flex-wrap are supported properties, but the values pertaining to wrapping are not supported).

Third, you've got `justify-content: space-around`, but its 2009 counterpart is set to `box-pack: center`.  Center is center in all drafts.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ccamtvl5

```
.flex-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: end;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) { /* hide from incomplete Firefox versions */
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

**Update**:  Wrapping now works in Firefox as of version 28, but only when using the modern properties (not the old prefixed ones like `display: -moz-box`).

Comment: so it's not possible to use that in order to target android >=2.3? What I really want is to have 3 buttons in one row and the rest 3 in a second one. Do you suggest using css2 with float ans center properties?

Comment: Sadly, no.  Centering inline-block list elements is a reasonably attractive fallback for incomplete Flexbox support:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/lBDwu

Answer (score 1):

> display: -webkit-box;

You probably meant `-webkit-flex`.