# iOS flexbox syntax and equal height grid cell

Tags: mobile, flexbox

I have a bit of a form to optimise for mobile (in a mobile.css).
I have no control on the html at all.

I'm trying to align them in a 2 columns layout  and have the cell on the same row be equal height (if possible without js).

I tried with display table and flex but i can't seem to make that work.

http://codepen.io/zapatoche/professor/BcGmD

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Flexbox is not really an option in this instance when mobile is involved because wrapping isn't available (see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773928/flexbox-and-wrap-property)

Comment: I've tried an alternate version, which coudl work only i the last element is alone on the row. http://codepen.io/zapatoche/live/KcdlJ. might try javascript then to keep the thing flexible.