# How to wrap boxes in section?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

A have a `<section>` and `<article>`s. I would like to move all `<article>` elements and resize to width 100%, when user resizes browser. I try to do it with `flex-box`. Here is what I want to achieve

[image: img]

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KkawJ/1/)

```
section, article {
display: box;
}

article {
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
    display:-moz-box; /* Firefox */
    display:-webkit-box; /* Safari and Chrome */
    display:-ms-flexbox; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    display:box;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section {
    display: -moz-box-flex;
    background: blue;    
}
```

Comment: You have quite a few things going on wrong here.  `display: box` is from the old 2009 Flexbox draft, which is on its way out (see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662578/flexible-box-model-display-flex-box-flexbox).  No 2009 Flexbox implementation in any browser supports wrapping, and Firefox currently does not support wrapping with their modern implementation either (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773928/flexbox-and-wrap-property).  Box-flex is not a display property.  Your 2nd diagram can only be achieved with the *column* orientation, which requires using fixed heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `max-width` you have set on them.

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bTpW9/) - I removed the left/right `margins`.