# how to break a flex box navigation into 2 lines at mobile viewport

Tags: html, css, nav, flexbox

I want to break the top navbar into 2 lines when seen this in mobile screen that is `@media screen and (max-width: 480px`

This is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/7PuCc/

```css
.index nav{display: -ms-flexbox;
    /*display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;*/
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    display: flex; display: -ms-flexbox; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [flexbox and wrap property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773928/flexbox-and-wrap-property)

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to split the the list into two 's.

Mobile viewport could get a `flex-direction: column` and anything wider than that would get `flex-direction: row`.

Check out the sample : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lnpfu