# Flexbox - flex-wrap on older devices

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've used flexbox to create a 2 column layout with a div at the top spanning both columns (I'm using this for a menu layout). The following fiddle shows how I've achieved this. Unfortunately, while it works perfectly in Chrome/iOS 7, it doesn't seem to work in older versions of Safari.
http://jsfiddle.net/Jtts9/

I don't need to support IE, but does need to support Android/iOS. This displays correctly in Chrome and iOS7, but when I use the old syntax (e.g. `display: -webkit-box;`), I can't replicate the two columns, as `flex-flow: row wrap` doesn't seem to exist in the older syntax. I've seen a few references to `box-lines`, but it sounds like this was not supported.

How would I go about achieving the same look while using the old 2009 flexbox syntax?

Comment: Have you looked into Autoprefixer? It takes care of all of that kind of thing for you. You can specify which browsers to support. Highly recommended: http://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/

Comment: possible duplicate of [flexbox and wrap property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773928/flexbox-and-wrap-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up on the old flexbox syntax in the end, and went with float and pseudo-selectors.

This fiddle shows the solution, compared to the original problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/HQPKM/7/

What I've done is apply `float: left` to all the items, and then used the following:

```
.item2 :nth-child(2){
    float: right;
}
```

to float every second element to the right.

Additionally, to replicate the behaviour of flexbox when an odd number of items were present, I added the following rule:

```
.item2:last-child:not(:nth-child(odd)){
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
}
```

This makes the final box span the complete width if there are an odd number of boxes.