# Desktop & mobile backwards compatible flexbox implementation - Safari in particular

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I am having big issues getting my flexbox implementation working on Safari mobile and desktop and Android. It is working for Chrome and IE11 pretty much. Would also be nice if it is working for IE Mobile, earlier versions of IE and Firefox. This is what I have:

```
display:flex; 
display:-webkit-flex; 
display:-ms-flexbox;

flex-flow: row wrap; 
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
-ms-flex-flow: row wrap; 

justify-content:space-around; 
-webkit-justify-content:space-around; 
-ms-justify-content:space-around;  

align-items:center; 
-webkit-align-items:center; 
-ms-align-items:center;
```

How do I change the above to make it mostly (backwards) compatible for the biggest desktop and mobile browers? There is a dearth of information regarding this topic.

Also, does the **wrap** property work for Safari at all? I am having particularly significant issues for that one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [flexbox and wrap property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773928/flexbox-and-wrap-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: http://zomigi.com/blog/flexbox-presentation/ -- see links on this page (to CSS-tricks Using Old and New Syntax article, especially -- and this: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

...show how mixing the old and new syntax and prefixes in proper order (the Cascading part of Cascading Style Sheets) will provide the best cross browser/version support for flexbox at this point.

hope this helps with future projects, until flexbox is more clearly implemented...

-AK

Comment: also see my own answer as an addition to this answer

Comment: I ended up bagging on flexbox on my current project because of firefox's lack of wrapping, dammit! Firefox!

Comment: Couldn't assume all users would have the most current browser, and the SASS/Compass route to forcing flexbox to work became more effort than it was going to be worth...  Also, caniuse still has the small print that "For Firefox 28- it refers to lack of flex-wrap & flex-flow support."

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The secret for me was to have the non-prefixed flex-box properties last in each series instead of first. I don't know why that worked though.