# Flex items not wrapping in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of divs inside a flex div like this with **Chrome**:

[image]

But in **Firefox** it does horizontal scroll only with one line

[image]

What can I do to don't force the horizontal scroll? I want it in Firefox like in Chrome

```
#maindiv{
    margin: auto;
    width: 97%;
    border: 1px solid #F4F4F4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    height: 395px;
    max-height: 395px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#divslist{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: end;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [flexbox and wrap property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773928/flexbox-and-wrap-property)

Answer (score 2):

just changed the order in css from

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
display: -moz-box;
```

To

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-box;
display: flex;
```

and its working in FF 28.check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jU7s2/4/) in FF and chrome

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of FF versions that don't support wrapping.

Comment: Please mention the version of FF you are using