# Error with display: flex on safari?

Tags: html, css

Just uploading a webpage to my domain and its not working on safari, i am using all the prefixes though. The error is clearly with the display: flex feature.

Here is what is should look like (chrome)
[image: What is should look like (chrome)]

Here is how it looks on safari 
[image: Here is how it looks on safari]
Here is my CSS:

```
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-webkit-flexbox;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-moz-flex;
  display:-moz-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
```

I have used quite a lot of flex in this homepage and all the items not centered or space between on the nav is not correct!

My website is http://oliverkle.in

Comment: Can u please specify clearly about what is not working?

Comment: I will screenshot it for you and explain and share the edit

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16775245/128165 for some equivalent *old* properties/values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test my solution on your website, as you've changed it since making the original post (great website, by the way!) however, **try re-ordering those statements**.

Using the order of properties from your code impacted one of my existing pages, in Safari, however it works fine ordered like this:

```
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-webkit-flexbox;
  display:-moz-flex;
  display:-moz-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
```